# Pygame : Missing events on high CPU load

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, pygame, mouseevent

I'm working with pygame on a graphical application, involving some video computation, and mouse events listening. I'm using a raspberry 3, raspbian jessie and python2.7.

As the title said : i'm loosing some mouse events, especially when the CPU load is high. I managed to reproduce this behavior in this small exemple :

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Crash!')
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
running = True
Rectplace = pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0),(100, 100, 100, 100))
pygame.display.update()
while running:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(`event`)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

When running this script, most of the mouse wheel events (buttons 4&5) are discarded on fast roll. Removing the `time.sleep(0.1)`,that simulate CPU load, make the event listener perfectly reliable.

As i can't remove the slow computation part, nor optimize it more, what should i do to get back these events ?

Thank you for sharing your brains !

Comment: Threading and a queue for the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that pygame use a limited size circular event queue.  When full, each new event replaces the oldest event.   If you get more events than you can ever handle, then let them go, as you will have to discard them anyway.

If you have sporadic slow computations, so that catching up may be feasible, then you must break up the computation into pieces short enough in time that you can get events before the default queue is full.  When you get them, either process immediately or put into a larger catch_up queue.  The best way to do that depends on the details of the code.

Or investigate the suggested thread solution.